# Interactive Brokers and MATLAB Connection

Tags: matlab, connection, quantitative-finance, interactive-brokers

I'm trying to connect MATLAB to interactive brokers. I'm aware there was a bug before. However, I got an email in August saying it was fixed. I'm currently running this code;

```
% establish connection to TWS ib = ibtws('',7497);

%% create currency handles ibEURUSD = ib.Handle.createContract; % set forex credentials ibEURUSD.symbol = 'EUR'; ibEURUSD.secType = 'CASH'; ibEURUSD.exchange = 'IDEALPRO'; ibEURUSD.currency = 'USD';

cur = getdata(ib,ibEURUSD);

% close IB connection close(ib);
```

Getting the result for cur of "not connected", has anyone managed to get IB working with MATLAB, if so could you point towards a good resource?

Thanks

Allan

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [IB-Matlab connector](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/IB-Matlab) (https://undocumentedmatlab.com/IB-Matlab), which is actively maintained since 2010 and is the highest-rated product on [IB's Marketplace](https://gdcdyn.interactivebrokers.com/Universal/servlet/MarketPlace.MarketPlaceServlet?action=softwareTools&selectedClient=tradersInvestors) by a large margin.